# Which linux distro suits my computer?

Tags: gnome, kde, mate

I have HP Compaq NC6400 with 128mb ATI Mobiltiy X1300 graphics.
1280x800 display.
Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0 ghz
3gb ram
x64 based processor
2006 model laptop

I know this is Ubuntu site but kindly give me some independent suggestion because there are over 300+ Linux distros.

Thanks.

Comment: As you correctly deduced, this site is all about Ubuntu. So what advice do you expect except Ubuntu? This type of question is also too opinion-based for the site's format. However, my personal suggestion would be to use a lightweight Ubuntu flavour like Xubuntu or Lubuntu, maybe rather 14.04 than 16.04 because of ATI graphics (you should try that in a live session before installing) and maybe rather the 32 bit version to reduce RAM requirements a bit more. It's all just an opinion though.

Comment: The only SE site where you can ask this kind of question is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but you still need to specify more details before posting there.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: pick any you like and see if it works well enough.

The one thing that would most likely cause problems and sluggishness is the graphics chipset.  It is listed as working on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver but I had a M200/X1100 myself and from 14.04 it became simply too sluggish.  So you need to try and decide for yourself.

If the graphics chipset holds up, you can most likely run a full blown [Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/), in 64-bit mode.

If that's too sluggish to your liking, try in order Lubuntu and then XUbuntu.  After that, you most likely have to divert to other distros that are [targeted to slower computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestion links to pick your distro:

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/distro-picker-0

http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/personality/quizshow.php?title=Which-Linux-distribution-are-you-1&q=1

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/distro-indecision-cheats-guide-choosing-linux-distribution/

http://lifehacker.com/5889950/how-to-find-the-perfect-linux-distribution-for-you

http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/best-linux-distro-five-we-recommend-1090058

I would highly recommend Ubuntu or Lubuntu for you. But you can decide :)